# Python - %s must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON querying from MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to do a select on a mongodb database using python.

If I pull all documents from the collection it works:

```
     mongo_docs = instance_col.find()
```

`instance_col` is my column in mongodb.

However I need to query for a specific AWS account number and that's where it falls apart.

If I do:

```
    query = "Account Number : " +  aws_account_number
    mongo_docs = instance_col.find({query})
```

My script crashes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances.py", line 766, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances.py", line 639, in main
    mongo_export_to_file(interactive, aws_account, aws_account_number)
  File "C:\Users\tdun0002\OneDrive - Company Technologies\Desktop\important_folders\Company\git\jf_cloud_scripts\aws_scripts\python\aws_tools\ec2_mongo.py", line 223, in mongo_export_to_file
    mongo_docs = instance_col.find({query})
  File "C:\Users\tdun0002\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 1460, in find
    return Cursor(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tdun0002\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 143, in __init__
    validate_is_mapping("filter", spec)
  File "C:\Users\tdun0002\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\common.py", line 472, in validate_is_mapping
    raise TypeError("%s must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, or "
TypeError: filter must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, or any other type that inherits from collections.Mapping
```

This is what the records look like in my mongo database:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ff32fe910541fea330a59b3"), "AWS Account" : "company", "Account Number" : "012345678910", "Name" : "B-product--antispam-d984", "Instance ID" : "i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "AMI ID" : "ami-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "Volumes" : "vol-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, vol-0d469d1595f99b81c", "Private IP" : "10.245.137.140", "Public IP" : null, "Private DNS" : "ip-10-245-137-140.ec2.internal", "Availability Zone" : "us-east-1b", "VPC ID" : "vpc-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "Type" : "t3.medium", "Key Pair Name" : "amp-company-dept-dev", "State" : "running", "Launch Date" : "November 23 2020" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ff32fe910541fea330a59b5"), "AWS Account" : "company", "Account Number" : "012345678910", "Name" : "B-product--staticweb-a52f", "Instance ID" : "i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "AMI ID" : "ami-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "Volumes" : "vol-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, vol-01163ccf4372cf0aa", "Private IP" : "10.245.137.233", "Public IP" : null, "Private DNS" : "ip-10-245-137-233.ec2.internal", "Availability Zone" : "us-east-1b", "VPC ID" : "vpc-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "Type" : "t3.medium", "Key Pair Name" : "amp-company-dept-dev", "State" : "running", "Launch Date" : "November 23 2020" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ff32fe910541fea330a59b7"), "AWS Account" : "company", "Account Number" : "012345678910", "Name" : "B-product--campaigns-f08a", "Instance ID" : "i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "AMI ID" : "ami-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "Volumes" : "vol-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, vol-08d5b9114fe5b538a", "Private IP" : "10.245.137.176", "Public IP" : null, "Private DNS" : "ip-10-245-137-176.ec2.internal", "Availability Zone" : "us-east-1b", "VPC ID" : "vpc-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "Type" : "t3.medium", "Key Pair Name" : "amp-company-dept-dev", "State" : "running", "Launch Date" : "November 23 2020" }
```

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that `find` expects a dict or other mapping. However, you passed in a set. Try this instead:

```
instance_col.find({"Account Number": aws_account_number})
```